# Difference between native_apic_mem_write and native_apic_msr_write?

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm

I am new to linux kernel and do not know much about it. For some reason I have to trace the latency issues on linux host kernel and the kvm guest kernel as well. Now I just have to compare **native_apic_msr_write**(this is used in **linux host kernel**) with **naitve_apic_mem_write**(used in **kvm guset kernel**).

Based on my limited knowledge, I tried to read the source code for these two function calls, and I believe native_apic_msr_write is used to write a value to msr register(hope this is correct).
My problem is I don't understand what native_apic_mem_write does because it calls some inline assembly called ALTERNATIVE and I am not familiar with that, either.

I attached the code below.
Can some one explain what happens inside? It does not have to be very detailed. Any information would be helpful, thanks.

```
#define ALTERNATIVE(oldinstr, newinstr, feature)                        \
80                                                                         \
81       "661:\n\t" oldinstr "\n662:\n"                                    \
82       ".section .altinstructions,\"a\"\n"                               \
83       "  .long 661b - .\n"                      /* label           */   \
84       "  .long 663f - .\n"                      /* new instruction */   \
85       "  .word " __stringify(feature) "\n"      /* feature bit     */   \
86       "  .byte 662b-661b\n"                     /* sourcelen       */   \
87       "  .byte 664f-663f\n"                     /* replacementlen  */   \
88       ".previous\n"                                                     \
89       ".section .discard,\"aw\",@progbits\n"                            \
90       "  .byte 0xff + (664f-663f) - (662b-661b)\n" /* rlen <= slen */   \
91       ".previous\n"                                                     \
92       ".section .altinstr_replacement, \"ax\"\n"                        \
93       "663:\n\t" newinstr "\n664:\n"            /* replacement     */   \
94       ".previous"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are [SMP alternatives](http://lwn.net/Articles/164121/) - a way for the same binary kernel to run different instructions on SMP and UP systems.